# Скролл у position:fixed div

Tags: css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь сделать следующее: два блока с таблицами, которые располагаются слева и справа, соответственно. При этом правая таблица (на рисунке ниже отмечена синим) плавающая - при сролле основной левой таблицы правая следует за ней, оставаясь всегда на виду. Однако если в правой таблице много строк (такое случается редко, но случается), то добраться до последних нет возможности - они прячутся, т.к. блок `position:fixed;`

Как тут быть? Чтобы правый блок оставался на виду при скролле левой таблицы, но при этом оставался на виду, а если там слишком много записей, то появлялся бы скролл и у этого блока? Есть возможность использовать bootstrap.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#date_range {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

div#samples_data_div {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div#samples_data_div,
div#orders_data_div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

div#orders_data_div {
  width: 49%;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  left: 51%;
}

#order_data {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="date_range" class="row text-center">Управление</div>
  <div id="samples_data_div">
    <table border='1'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="orders_data_div">
    <div id="order_data">
      <table border='1'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант растянуть на весь экран и добавить overflow auto.

```css
#date_range {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

div#samples_data_div {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div#samples_data_div,
div#orders_data_div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

div#orders_data_div {
  width: 49%;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  left: 51%;
}

#order_data {
  position: fixed;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="date_range" class="row text-center">Управление</div>
  <div id="samples_data_div">
    <table border='1'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="orders_data_div">
    <div id="order_data">
      <table border='1'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
```